# Included class inside another class is not declared PHP

Tags: php, class, phpseclib

I have the following __construct of a selfmade class;

```
public function __construct($ip, $user, $pass, $product) {
    $this->_ip = $ip;
    $this->_user = $user;
    $this->_pass = $pass;
    $this->_product = $product;

    $this->ssh = new Net_SSH2($this->_ip);
    if (!$this->ssh->login($this->_user, $this->_pass)) {
        return 'Login Failed';
    }
    $this->sftp = new Net_SFTP($this->_ip);
    if (!$this->sftp->login($this->_user, $this->_pass)) {
        return 'Login Failed';
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that it says Net_SSH2 and Net_SFTP is not declared, but I have included those classes at the page, im not sure, but can it be that I have to pass those classes into this class instead of just calling them?
If yes, how do I do that?

Comment: are you sure they really got included? try `require` instead and see if something blows up.

Comment: Okay I did, and yes they are included, also when I include them again, it does blows up, so yes they are included.

Comment: in which case, perhaps there's a namespace issue of some sort. `new \Net_SFTP(...)` or something like.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to use autoload.

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once $class_name . '.php';
}
```

Now, when you ask for a new class, it will be auto loaded.

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included those classes using a `require`, `include` or an autoload function?

If you haven't, make sure the files in which those classes are defined are loaded.

Now, we need to check for the namespace.

At the top of the `Net_SFTP`, is there a `namespace [SOMETHING]`? If there is, you must refer to the fully qualified class name, or `use` this class.

An example:

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\BundleName;

class Net_SFTP { 
    ....
}

?>
```

Now, in order to use this class, we must do one of the following:

```
<?php

use VendorName\BundleName\Net_SFTP;

...
$this->ssh = new Net_SFTP(...);
...
?>
```

Or, directly:

```
<?php

...
$this->ssh = new VendorName\BundleName\Net_SFTP(...);
...

?>
```

Comment: Well it seems that the Net_SFTP class is loaded, but it is because of the IP address, when I leave the IP address empty, it says couldnt not connect, but when I insert a random IP or website, it just closes the php request, wierd it is...

Comment: @user3041757 - sounds like that's another issue unrelated to your original post. That said, if you're calling just `Net_SFTP()` (since you said "when [you] eave the IP address empty" it makes since that it wouldn't be able to connect. And as for "when [you] insert a random IP or website"...  do the random IP's have SSH servers on them? And by website do you mean hostname? Because obviously ht tp://www.mydomain.com/ isn't going to be a valid server name.